# Chaining Animations in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a menu whose contents are hidden by default, but whose visibility can be toggled on and off by clicking on a given element.

That's simple enough by itself, but where I'm getting stuck is when I try to add a chained animation to the function.

In a nutshell, here's what I'd like to accomplish:

1. On document load, hide the unordered list containing the menu items. At the same time, change the opacity of the menu items to 0.
2. When the menu toggle element is clicked, first animate the menu by sliding it down (using slideToggle), then fade in the menu items to full opacity.
3. When the menu is open and the toggle element is clicked, fade out the menu items by returning them to zero opacity, then animate the closing of the menu by sliding it back up.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="menu-toggle"><a href="#">Toggle</a></p>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.menu-toggle {
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // set some variables
    var menu_toggle = $('.menu-toggle');
    var menu = $('.menu');
    var menu_li = menu.find('li');

    // hide the menu as soon as the DOM is ready
    menu.hide();

    // change the initial opacity of the menu items
    menu_li.css({
        opacity: 0
    });

    // toggle the menu on clicking the control  
    menu_toggle.click(function () {
        menu.slideToggle(500, function () {
            menu_li.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Finally, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EYmPA/

With the current code, I've accomplished #1 from above. I've accomplished #2, but only for the first time the toggle element is clicked. Thereafter, only the menu slide appears to work. And finally, #3 only works partially; the menu closing animations works fine, but the list items do not fade out as needed.

I've been working on this for a while now and can't seem to get the desired effect. Any ideas on how to make this work as intended would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work exactly how you are describing it (chrome on mac), except for when you say "..., then fade..."   Do you actually mean for the animation to finish sliding, THEN fade? or do you want the animation AND fade to happen at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking to have the first animation complete before the second starts. The other thing is that the fade in only works the first time through, not on any subsequent clicks, and the fade out doesn't work at all. Note: I'm using large durations now, just for the sake of being able to see the sequence properly; these will be adjusted to much smaller values later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code:

```
var menuShown = 0;
// toggle the menu on clicking the control  
menu_toggle.click(function () {
    if(menuShown){
        menu.slideUp(500, function(){
            menu_li.animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
            menuShown = 0;
        })
    }else{
        menu.slideDown(500, function(){
            menu_li.animate({ opacity: 1}, 500);
            menuShown = 1;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EYmPA/50/)**

Comment: Thanks - this is very close. The only thing not quite working is the animation of menu_li opacity (from 1 to 0) in the 'if' statement. Looking at the code, I can't see what would be causing that to hang up, though.

Comment: Must've been at this too long. The reason the the animation of menu_li opacity (from 1 to 0) in the 'if' statement isn't working is because it's chained *after* the slideUp. Reverse the two animations and it's working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/emf66/1/. Thanks again for your help.